# Typeset a number in hexdecimal format (preferably math mode)

Tags: math-mode, formatting, numbering

Is there a macro for formatting numbers in programming style `0x` hex notation, e.g. instead of `-1155484576` have `0xbb20b460`. I would like to embed these numbers in a math mode context.

E.g. if I just type

```
$\langle 0xbb20b460, 0xd4d95138, 0x3d93cb7a \rangle$
```

the numbers aren't properly displayed.

Comment: Put `\text{}` around them (`amstext` or `amsmath` packages). Also, since the notation `0x` is used in programming, perhaps you could also use a monospaced font. Use `\texttt{}` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, just using `\texttt` is actually not that bad, looks ok.

Comment: I'd choose `\mathtt`, so not to risk the font comes out italic in an italic context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so using `\texttt` or `\mathtt` is fine.

Comment: Actually, I would like some alternative to this, in which the the digits look more like usual math numbers.

Comment: @einpoklum try `\mathrm`